# How to set column name when creating a view?

Tags: db2, metadata, db2-midrange

By default, when creating a view, for the name of each column, if the column is a direct selection from a table/physical file, then it will use the name of that table/physical file's column. If it's not (e.g. a `CASE` statement), then it's blank.

How can I override it to set what I want for the view's columns' names?

Answer (score 1):

Simple: use an alias

```
SELECT ... CASE something WHEN 'somethingelse' ... END AS whatever, ...
```

The above will have the alias of `WHATEVER`. You can even get fancy and quote the alias:

`... AS "Something Else"`

which will have the alias of `Something Else`.

Alternatively, you can assign view column names via

```
CREATE VIEW some_view (some_column_name) AS
SELECT
  CASE ... END
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Db2 for i particularly but if what you are calling the *Text* for a column is actaully the LABEL, then try the `LABEL` command

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzlabelon.htm

or, if what you are calling the *Text* for a column is actaully the COMMENT, then try the `COMMENT` command

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzxcomnt.htm